# Bouncing balls - balls passing through boundaries

Tags: java

I've created a bouncing balls animation, that's drawn on a surface (library from my university) that has 2 frames in it, and 2 arrays of balls that half goes to the first frame and the second to the second frame.
For some reason - the balls pass through to y and x axis of their frame.
I've already tried doing some of the solutions that were suggested (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767932/setting-boundaries-of-animated-balls)) and it didn't help..

my code:

```
public static void updateBalVelocity(Ball ball, int width, int height,
                                     int minWidth, int minHeight) {
    //  get default value of the dx and dy
    double dx = ball.getVelocity().getDx();
    double dy = ball.getVelocity().getDy();

    //  check if the ball is touching the border (x/y axis) and if so -
    //  change it's directions
    if ((ball.getX() + ball.getSize() + dx) >= width) {
        dx = (dx > 0) ? -dx : dx;
    } else if ((ball.getX() - ball.getSize()) <= minWidth) {
        dx = Math.abs(dx);
    }

    if ((ball.getY() + ball.getSize() + dy) >= height) {
        dy = (dy > 0) ? -dy : dy;
    } else if ((ball.getY() - ball.getSize()) <= minHeight) {
        dy = Math.abs(dy);
    }

    //  apply the velocity to the ball
    ball.setVelocity(dx, dy);
}

 public static void moveBalls(Ball[] balls, DrawSurface d, int height,
                             int width, int minHeight, int minWidth) {
    for (Ball ball : balls) {
        updateBalVelocity(ball, width, height, minWidth, minHeight);
        ball.moveOneStep();
        d.setColor(ball.getColor());
        d.fillCircle(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getSize());
        ball.drawOn(d);
    }
}
```

and in the run method:

```
 while (true) {
        ...

        //  move balls
        BouncingBallHelper.moveBalls(ballsD1, d, 500, 500, 50, 50);
        BouncingBallHelper.moveBalls(ballsD2, d, 600, 600, 450, 450);
        gui.show(d);

        // wait for 50 milliseconds.
        sleeper.sleepFor(50);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and step through when it touches the border?

Comment: I have, and it shows that it's being updated correctly.. I have no idea what goes wrong